# Averaging periodic data with a variable sampling rate

Tags: matlab, average, interpolation

I have a long array of `[x,y]` coordinate values of a toy car running around a track for 5-6 laps. The number of data points is inconsistent per lap (the laps have anywhere between 50-60 `[x,y]` points). The data plotted in Matlab makes sense, and it plots the car as it moves around the track:

[image: plot]

However I need to somehow average the noisy laps to create a more accurate single map of the track.

I have tried marking the beginning the the track in order to identify the start of a new lap and then average each corresponding point from each lap however due to the different amount of data points for each lap this leads to more errors.

I thought about sorting the `[x,y]` data to join all of the points into one lap, but this doesn't work since the track is circular.

Does anyone know of a way to somehow average together my data to merge the laps together?

Comment: Is your track circular?

Comment: It's actually a rounded rectangle in this case, but ideally I'd want a solution that works on any track shape

Comment: Is you aim to make a map of the track (because you don't know the track) or to more accurately track the car's movements (and you know the shape of the track)?

Comment: @Wolfie The car speed is constant but I didn't collect any time data for this plot. Would time help to merge the laps together? - I just need to know the general shape of the unknown track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to define the beginning of the track and then parameterize each traversal around the loop by the normalized arc-length of the path. You can then interpolate each of the curves at specific intervals along the track using this parameterization and average the result.

```
% Assume that the first point is the start point (t = 0)
start_point = path(1,:);

% Compute the distance to this point for all data points
distances = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, path, start_point).^2, 2));

% Find the minima of this curve (these are all the times that the car passed the start)
% We apply some smoothing to get rid of necessary noise. Really depends on your data
[~, locs] = findpeaks(smooth(-distances, 20));

% Make sure we include the first and last point
locs = [1; locs; numel(distances)];

% Desired samples for each loop
nSamples = 1000;

% Pre-allocate the outputs
xpoints = zeros(numel(locs) - 1, nSamples);
ypoints = zeros(numel(locs) - 1, nSamples);

for k = 1:(numel(locs) - 1)
    % Get the coordinates recorded for this particular loop
    loop_points = path(locs(k):locs(k+1),:);

    % Compute the cumulative arc-length using these points
    arc_length = cumsum([0; sum(diff(loop_points, [], 1).^2, 2)]);

    % Normalize the arc_length between 0 and 1
    arc_length = arc_length ./ arc_length(end);

    % Interpolate along the curve
    xpoints(k,:) = interp1(arc_length, loop_points(:,1), linspace(0, 1, nSamples));
    ypoints(k,:) = interp1(arc_length, loop_points(:,2), linspace(0, 1, nSamples));
end

% Average all the x and y locations
X = mean(xpoints, 1);
Y = mean(ypoints, 1);

plot(X, Y)
```

We can test this by going in a perfect circle and add some noise to each circuit and change the number of samples each time

```
nLoops = 10;

x = [];
y = [];

for k = 1:nLoops
    nSamples = randi([50, 70]);

    t = linspace(0, 2*pi, nSamples + 1);
    t(end) = [];

    x = cat(1, x(:), cos(t(:)) + 0.1 * (rand(size(t(:))) - 0.5));
    y = cat(1, y(:), sin(t(:)) + 0.1 * (rand(size(t(:))) - 0.5));
end

path = [x(:), y(:)];
```

[image]

> NOTE: `findpeaks` and `smooth` are toolbox functions that can likely be replaced with functions from the MATLAB File Exchange. Alternately, if you *know* when the car passes the beginning already, you can remove the usage of `findpeaks` altogether.

Comment: This seems pretty effective from your demo. Perhaps worth mentioning that [`findpeaks`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html?searchHighlight=findpeaks&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) and [`smooth`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smooth.html?searchHighlight=smooth&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) use the signal processing and curve fitting toolboxes respectively.

Comment: @Wolfie Updated with the caveat

Comment: @Suever Thanks this seems to be a very good solution, however I'm get some Matlab errors with my data. When I enter the for loop it stops running and says "The grid vectors are not strictly monotonic increasing." Do you know what this means?

Comment: @enrico  Do you have multiple points at the same location? Check what the value of `locs` is in that pariticular iteration

Comment: Ah yes that was it thanks! It works fine now with the duplicates removed